How do I hide this icon in Rider?
How do I make Rider not show this icon? It appears next to equal or non-equal sign when I work with Unity code.
I tried looking through "Inlay hints" section of Preferences but could not fild the needed checkbox.
Stackoverflow is still asking me to write details, even though I have written everything there is to say. So you can ignore this paragraph.


That icon indicates that an implicit Unity object lifetime check is performed in this spot. It is shown by the appropriate inspection, Implicit check for Unity object lifetime. You can hide this icon by disabling the inspection in Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings | Inspection Severity | C# > Unity > Implicit check for Unity object lifetime.
There is also an open request to allow hiding this icon without disabling the inspection: RIDER-111432 Make inline icons for Unity lifetime checks optional. Please upvote the request, if you are also interested.

